# php find value between character from string

Tags: php, string, char

Consider the string 1,2,3,4

I want to extract 1 2 3 4 and store it in array. This code

```
for($i=0; $i<strlen($multi_event_value); $i++)
{
    if(is_numeric(substr($multi_event_value,$i,1)))
    {       
        $multi_event[$t] = substr($multi_event_value,$i,1);
        $t++;
    }
}
```

is working fine but if values are 10,11,12,14 then I get 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 4 but i want values to be 10 11 12 14. Same if values are 100,101 and so on.

Comment: Use either the ordinary `explode()` function or a regular expression.

Comment: why negative vote man....is it wrong to ask such Questions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode)

```
$arr = explode(',', '1,2,3,4'); // $arr = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
```

Comment: same way for javascript any function ?

Comment: In JS, you'll want to call the `split` method of the string object. E.g: `"1,2,3,4".split(',')`

Answer (score 1):

string.split(separator,limit) both parameters are optional

Comment: Care to elaborate on your answer? We encourage well formulated and explained answer (just odn't write a blog post :) )